# Exception thrown with taking a two dimentional array input. I'm getting an unexpected exception but my code looks okay

Tags: java, arrays, exception

I am getting an ArrayIndexOutofBound exception after taking two rows as input in a 3X3 matrix (n=3). It throws an exception as soon as I take the 6th integer as input, i.e., complete my second row.

```
int i, j;
System.out.println("Enter number of rows and columns");
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
int n = s.nextInt();
int[][] a = new int[n][n];
for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    for(j = 0; i < n; j++)
    {
        a[i][j] = s.nextInt();
    }
}
s.close();
```

Comment: Typo : `for(j=0;i<n;j++){` -> `for(j=0;j<n;j++){`

Comment: Lol. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

You made a simple typo in the `j` loop:

```
int i,j;
System.out.println("Enter number of rows and columns");
Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
int n=s.nextInt();
int[][] a=new int[n][n];
for(i=0;i<n;i++){
 for(j=0;j<n;j++){  // This line had a typo.
    a[i][j]=s.nextInt();
 }
}
s.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

The second for loop has a typo and try using try-with-resources for automatically closing the streams.

```
    int i, j;
    System.out.println("Enter number of rows and columns");
    try (Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in)) {
        int n = s.nextInt();
        int[][] a = new int[n][n];
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                a[i][j] = s.nextInt();
            }
        }
    } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. But if I use the above code, I won't get an exception thrown at me, but my code would still not function because of the typo and the catch block will handle my Exception. Am I right here, and if I am, what is the use of the try-catch blocks if my code is still non-functional?

Comment: You need to fix the typo in all cases. The use of try/cacth will help you to catch unexpected failure/behavior of your app E.g.you can show the user proper error message so he will not be confused after seeing a unexpected behavior. The use of try with resources will improve your code.
E.g. if you get an exception without try catch, lets say InputMismatchException, you Scanner will stay open even if you have scanner.close() in your code but if you use try-with-resources the resources, which implements AutoCloseable interface (Scanner is one of them), will close in case of error (exception).